# Cannot connect to MySQL using NodeJS, Express

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to connect to MySQL via nodeJS app using express for server, ive read the mysql npm documentation in order to begin connection but it seems like i get the error from the callback function i wrote inside createConnection.connect() and im using phpmyadmin just to see results and charts

here is my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql'); 
require('dotenv').config();
const workers = require('./routes/workers');


app.use('/', workers);


const DB = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
   user     : 'root',
  charset: 'utf8_general_ci',
  password: '',

});

DB.connect((err) => {
     throw `error: ${err}`
 });

 app.listen(process.env._PORT, () => {
     console.log(`Server is running on ${process.env._PORT}`);
 });
```

Comment: Can you share your error while you getting on database connection?

Comment: please give us the error details, also I prefer [mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) than [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql)

Comment: error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking **error** after connection. You have to check is there any error while database connection like following.

```
DB.connect((err) => {
     if(err){
        throw `error: ${err}`       
     }
     console.log("Database connected successfully");
 });
```

Answer (score -2):

Install sequelizejs , mysql ,mysql2 libararies

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize(dbName, username, password,{ host: localhost,
    // data type
    dialect: mysql,
});
```

You can use the .authenticate() function to test if the connection is OK:

```
try {
  await sequelize.authenticate();
  console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', error);
}
```